# Unserializing PHP array in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, serialization, deserialization

One of the former developers in an old system I'm working on used PHP [`serialize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) to flatten one array of data into one column of a MySQL table.

I need to write a complex query that involves this column. Is there a way to unserialize the data (even if it's into a comma separated string) within the SQL query or do I need to pass the results back to PHP?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html if any help you else you need to use php or you want to explode comma values?

Comment: well its not possible since mysql does not know anything about PHP serialize() so u need PHP  to handle the unserialize()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serialized PHP data is just a string, so for "simple" searches, you can use basic MySQL string operations.

e.g. The serialized array has a `name` parameter and you need to match against that, so

```
... WHERE LOCATE(CONCAT('s:', LENGTH('foo'), ':foo') ,serializeddatafield) > 0
```

which would produce

```
WHERE LOCATE('s:3:foo', serializeddata) > 0
```

But then, this would find **ANY** strings whose value is `foo` anywhere in the data, and not necessarily in the particular array field you want.

e.g. you're probably better off yanking out the whole field, deserializing in PHP, and then doing the search there. You could use the above technique to minimize the total number of strings you'd have to yank/parse, however.